# inserting data with different value then source in temp table

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I need to pull data into a temp table so i can group it into a product type but we currently have different variants of a certain product and I need to insert all the variants as the original variant. I wrote the code as follows but it still isn't working

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT *
           FROM   sys.tables
           WHERE  name LIKE '#temp%')
  DROP TABLE #temp

CREATE TABLE #temp
  (
     Product      VARCHAR(max) NULL,
     failure_code VARCHAR(max) NULL
  )

IF Product IN ( 18, 19, 20, 23,
                24, 25 )
  SELECT Product = 'DSD 4136'

INSERT INTO #temp
            (Product,
             failure_code)
SELECT product.prod_desc AS Product,
       test_failure_code.failure_code
FROM   repair
       INNER JOIN test_failure_code
               ON repair.id_test_failure_code = test_failure_code.id_test_failure_code
       INNER JOIN production_event_details
               ON repair.id_production_event_details = production_event_details.id_production_event_details
       INNER JOIN product
               ON production_event_details.prod_id = product.prod_id
       INNER JOIN repair_scm_bom_item
               ON repair.id_repair = repair_scm_bom_item.id_repair
       INNER JOIN repair_fault
               ON repair_scm_bom_item.id_repair_fault = repair_fault.id_repair_fault
       INNER JOIN scm_bom_item
               ON repair_scm_bom_item.id_scm_bom_item = scm_bom_item.id_scm_bom_item
GROUP  BY product.prod_desc,
          test_failure_code.failure_code

SELECT *
FROM   #temp

DROP TABLE #temp
```

Comment: You should describe exactly what isn't working otherwise people can't really help.

Comment: The if product in statement is failing. It does not change the descriptions to the new description i want

Comment: I tried using the product id as well but it still fails. I need all the variants of our DSD 4136 product to load onto the temp table as DSD 4136 so for the quality department.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The statement

```
IF Product IN ( 18, 19, 20, 23, 24, 25 )
SELECT Product = 'DSD 4136'
```

wont actually do anything, you need to use it in your insert statement using a CASE statement, this will select the product DSD 4136 when the product is one of your listed options:

```
INSERT INTO #temp
            (Product,
             failure_code)
SELECT CASE WHEN product.prod_desc IN ( 18, 19, 20, 23, 24, 25 ) THEN 'DSD 4136'
  ELSE product.prod_desc
END
AS Product,
       test_failure_code.failure_code
FROM   repair
       INNER JOIN test_failure_code
               ON repair.id_test_failure_code = test_failure_code.id_test_failure_code
       INNER JOIN production_event_details
               ON repair.id_production_event_details = production_event_details.id_production_event_details
       INNER JOIN product
               ON production_event_details.prod_id = product.prod_id
       INNER JOIN repair_scm_bom_item
               ON repair.id_repair = repair_scm_bom_item.id_repair
       INNER JOIN repair_fault
               ON repair_scm_bom_item.id_repair_fault = repair_fault.id_repair_fault
       INNER JOIN scm_bom_item
               ON repair_scm_bom_item.id_scm_bom_item = scm_bom_item.id_scm_bom_item
GROUP  BY product.prod_desc,
          test_failure_code.failure_code
```

Comment: Thanks Jamie  thanks a million it works like a charm